# How do I exit through the beacon in Faster Than Light mobile?

Tags: ios, ftl-faster-than-light

I recently purchased the Faster Than Light iOS app. I have just made it through my first map with the resistance hot on my heels. I arrived at the beacon and was about to exit through it when I realized. I don't know how. So my question simpler is: How do I exit through the beacon?

Comment: The body is to put *additional* info regarding your problem. There's a reason there's a minimum character limit. Please add more information about what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

(Although I don't have an iOS platform, I will assume that the behavior is consistent across all platforms. For reference this is a screenshot taken in Windows).

Upon reaching the Exit Beacon, your next jump has a new button at the right side of the Sector Map, designated as "Next Sector":

[image]

After clicking on the Next Sector button, the following menu appears, asking for what direction you want to take, besides the current layout of all sectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the exit beacon, there'll be a button in the top-right of the sector (?. Is that what it's called? The one you first see when you press Jump.) map. Pressing this will allow you to travel to new sectors.